# android4.4 after factory reset device, the system app can't receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast

Tags: java, android

Below is my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- 
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     -->

    <receiver android:name="com.tcl.receiver.BootReceiver">  
       <intent-filter>  
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
       </intent-filter>  
   </receiver>

   <service android:name="com.tcl.factoryresetservice.SystemMessageService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tcl.factoryresetservice.SystemMessageService" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

Below is my receive code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //start the service at boot completed
    if(intent.getAction().equals(BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.e(TAG,"Start SystemMessageService Service , curTime="+curTime);

        Intent i = new Intent(context,SystemMessageService.class);            
        context.startService(i);

    }
}
```

after factory reset the device, the system run, but my service doesn't run. if I reboot, it runs successfully. Why it happen like this, please help us, thanks.

Comment: If you factory reset the device wouldn't it delete your app and service?  Then you reinstall it, and then it works on the next reboot.

Comment: the service is the system service, I put it in the system app folder. So after factory reset, service is not deleted. but first reboot it doesn't run, next reboot run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Your UserPermission is correct

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Your receiver should be like this 
need to add permission in receiver

```
<receiver
android:name="com.tcl.receiver.BootReceiver"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Why only it doesn't receive after factory reset?